# emacs count c functions in a .c/.h src file

Tags: c, emacs

Does emacs have a function to count the no. of functions in .c/.h C src file?

I would like to be able to count a (large) no. of functions in a .c file and compare this to the no. of functions in the associated unit-test .c file to establish whether every function has a unit-test

ideally there is something built-in to do this as opposed to requiring some sort of reg-exp?

Comment: thinking about it, for .c, i should prob just count for reg-exp matches on lines containging only '{', or '}'. For .h I can just use M-x count-matches for ';' on the region containing the fn prototypes

Comment: well if you are certain that all whiles, if's, fors, switches etc follow the Egyptian bracing.

Comment: good point - a bit risky..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use semantic's tag generation to achieve this.

Semantic is a very powerful and underused feature of Emacs. Semantic can parse your .c and .h files and generate tags that you can look through to find your answer. I have written up examples for you:

First, ensure you have the `semantic` library loaded.

```lisp
(defun c--count-things-in-buffer (thing buffer)
  "return the count of THINGs in BUFFER.
THING may be: 'function, 'variable, or 'type"
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    ;; get the buffers tags, they will be generated if not already
    ;; then remove the ones that are not 'function tags
    ;; return the count of what is left
    (length (remove-if-not (lambda (tag) (equal thing (second tag)))
                          (semantic-fetch-tags)))))

(defun c-count-functions-in-buffer (buffer)
  "Count and message the number of function declarations in BUFFER"
  (interactive "b")
  (message "%s has %d functions"
           buffer
           (c--count-things-in-buffer 'function buffer)))

(defun c-count-variables-in-buffer (buffer)
  "Count and message the number of variable declarations in BUFFER"
  (interactive "b")
  (message "%s has %d variables"
           buffer
           (c--count-things-in-buffer 'variable buffer)))

(defun c-count-types-in-buffer (buffer)
  "Count and message the number of type declarations in BUFFER"
  (interactive "b")
  (message "%s has %d types"
           buffer
           (c--count-things-in-buffer 'type buffer)))
```

Try evaluating this in your scratch buffer then switch to your .c file and do `M-x` `c-count-functions-in-buffer`

The information brought back from `semantic-fetch-tags` has everything you need to solve your unit test problems.

Let's say you have a function called Foobar and your unit test are written like: Test_Foobar. You could get the tags for the .c file and the tags for the test file and do a check for every function in the c file there exists a tag in the test file that matches Test_. This would likely be better than simply counting the total number of functions.

Run this code in your scratch buffer with C-j:

```
(with-current-buffer "what-ever-your-c-buffer-is.c" (semantic-fetch-tags))
```

Here you'll be able to see all the great info that comes back that you can use for this.